# subscribe to all paypal webhooks events

Tags: paypal-webhooks

How can we subscribe to all events at a single time in paypal webhooks ?

```
{
"url": "https://www.yeowza.com/paypal_webhook",
"event_types": [
    {
        "name": "PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.CREATED"
    },
    {
        "name": "PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.VOIDED"
    }
]
```

}

This tells about subscribing to specific webhooks but not all webhooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following payload to subscribe to all webhooks :

```
"event_types": [
        {
            "name": “*"
        }
    ]
```

Please refer PayPal Webhooks documentation @ https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-webhook

> Note: To subscribe to all event types, use an * (asterisk) as a
>   wildcard for an event name in the event_types field. When you specify
>   the * wildcard for an event name in the event_types field, your
>   webhook is automatically subscribed to all event types, including any
>   new event types as support for them is added. This is also true when
>   you update an existing webhook by replacing a previously specified
>   array of event types with the * wildcard as the only event name. To
>   see all currently supported event types, you can issue a request to
>   Get a reference list of webhook event types.